# MS Access-VBA _ Save a Report to Hard Drive

Tags: ms-access, vba

need some help with this code if anyone can answer. Any suggestions are most appreciated.

I have a report that I want to save to my hard drive when clicking a button. When saving the report I want the filename to be created using two pieces of information from the report.

Variables:

```
  Report = "Contract"
  Save Location = "C:\Folder\"
  File Name = [Customer] &  " _ "  & [Date]
  File Type = PDF
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could save a macro and read the code in there.